# issue with formatting characters

Tags: python, struct

having a bit of an issue displaying characters

i have a payload recieved from a protocol request :

```
538cb9350404521a6c44020404563b152606102001085800020002aabb0000563b1526000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

the length of that is 509

what i want to display is the first 4 bytes, then 1 byte, then 1 byte

```
538cb935

04

04
```

currently to view the payload i am doing the following :

```
tm = struct.unpack(">L", payload[0:4])
print "Time : ", tm
ouroripv = struct.unpack(">b", payload[5])
print "Our onion address : "    
print "Ip version : ", ouroripv
ouroraddrlen = struct.unpack(">b", payload[6]) # Giving a length of 82 etc atm 
print "Ip length : ", ouroraddrlen
```

i get the result :

```
Time :  (1401731381,)
Our onion address : 
Ip version :  (4,)
Ip length :  (82,)
```

as you can see the Ip length, the 6th byte in on the payload is displaying 82 rather than the 4 it should be, what is the correct `struct.unpack` command that is needed to display this ?

how can i do this ?

Thanks guys

Comment: Are your sure you don't want payload[4], payload[5] instead of payload[5], payload[6]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python, the slicing doesn't include the last value, so `payload[0:4]` takes the first 4 bytes, from 0 to 3.

`payload[3]` is the fourth byte

`payload[4]` is the fifth byte

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot !, will mark is as an answer when i can :)